# Getting weird query string from Codigniter's LIKE()

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make a simple query in Codigniter like this:

```
$this->db->select("cats");
$this->db->from("pets");
$this->db->like("name", 'a', 'after');
```

And then show it:

```
echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```

Result:

```
SELECT cats FROM pets WHERE name LIKE 'a%' {escape '!'}
```

For some reason CI adds {escape '!'} at the end. Which of course generates an error when I try to run the query.

Database config:

```
$db['pyramid'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'pyramid',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'database' => '',
'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'WINDOWS-1252',
'dbcollat' => '',
    //'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

It works if I do it like this:

```
$this->db->select("cats");
$this->db->from("pets");
$this->db->where("name LIKE 'a%'", NULL, FALSE);
```

But then I'll have to escape the data myself.

**SECOND EDIT:**

It seems like CodeIgniter produces the correct query according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Maybe it's because it's a Pervasive database.

I've creted a new thread with a question on how to get around the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578077/cant-use-codeigniters-like) instead.

Comment: And what does $this->db->last_query() says ??

Comment: It doesn't get to that statement because I get a syntax error from the query.

Comment: Try `$this->db->select("cats")->where("name LIKE 'a%'", null, false)->get("pets");`

Comment: have you tried `$this->db->select("cats");$this->db->like("name", "a", "after");$this->db->get("pets");` ?

Comment: Use as i suggest till find something.. don't stuck on single problem man keep working  ;)

Comment: At my end `$var = $this->db->select("cats")->like("name", 'a', 'after')->get("pets");` running fine

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$var = $this->db->select("cats")->like("name", 'a', 'after')->get("pets")->result();
print_r($var);
```

Go to 363 of odbc driver and find or search with `_like_escape_str` you will definitely find something...

```
$sql .= " LIKE '".$this->escape_like_str($this->dbprefix)."%' ".sprintf($this->_like_escape_str, $this->_like_escape_chr);
```

and replace it with

```
$sql .= " LIKE '".$this->escape_like_str($this->dbprefix)."%' ";//or return false as needs
```

maybe this can help

Comment: I doesn't work on my side. Are you trying with the ODBC driver? I'm beginning to think that the driver is the problem.

Comment: Can't find it. Are you looking in system/database/odbc/odbc_driver.php? I'm running v3.0.0

Comment: yes see in variables you will find something like " {escape '%s'} "; search that variable in  system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_driver.php...

Comment: I found that string but not your suggestion in your post. I tried to replace it with an empty string and it works. It even seems to escape correctly. But it doesn't feel safe because I'm not sure what else depends on this. I'm geatful for your patience!

Comment: It will always create an error so just replace it and use it but make the original as comment //line so in future if you need that you can get... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:-

```
$this->db->select('cats')
$this->db->from('pets');
$this->db->like('name', 'a', 'after');
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

You can also write it by below way:-

```
$result = $this->db->select('cats')->from('pets')
       ->where("name LIKE a%")->get()->result_array();
```

Hope it will help you :)