# Can't use CodeIgniter's LIKE()

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Because of some bug or my lack of knowledge in ODBC connections I can't use CodeIgniter's

```
$this->db->like();
```

(If you really want to know why I can't use it, see my other thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407012/getting-weird-query-string-from-codigniters-like).)

How do I replace

```
$this->db->like("name", 'a', 'after');
```

with some other safe code?

**EDIT:**

Obviously, I wasn't clear in my description.

I KNOW how to use "like()". My problem is that I CAN'T use it because of other circumstances. What I need is a substitute for "like()".

I know I could do it like:

```
$this->db->where("name LIKE 'a%'", NULL, FALSE);
```

but that wouldn't be safe.

**EDIT 2:**

Maybe this could work:

```
$user_input = "a";

//Escape input
$escaped_input = $this->db->escape($user_input);

//add a %-sign to the end of the escaped input
$like_input = substr_replace($escaped_input, "%", -1, 0)

$this->db->where("name LIKE " . $like_input, NULL, FALSE);
```

But I get the feeling it would not prevent SQL injections.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ??

Comment: A database syntax error.

Comment: @ConnyOlsson show me error message

Answer (score 1):

There is 3 methods to follow.

1. **after**

   ```
   $this->db->like('name', 'a', 'after'); 
   // Output: WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
   ```
2. **before**

   ```
   $this->db->like('name', 'a', 'before'); 
   // Output: WHERE name LIKE '%a'
   ```
3. **both**

   ```
   $this->db->like('name', 'a', 'both'); 
   // Output: WHERE name LIKE '%a%'
   ```

> Check your database connection and database library loaded as well

[`$this->db->like()` in Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query#looking-for-similar-data)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my updated question.

Comment: use this `$this->db->like('name', 'a', 'after');`

Comment: No it cant. Or use normal MySQL code with `$this->db->query()`